# Compute $3^{100} \pmod {9797}$ using Euler's Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, totient-function, chinese-remainder-theorem

> Compute $3^{100} \pmod {9797}$. (Hint: You will want to use both Euler’s
>   Theorem and Chinese Remainder Theorem)

I can get to the step where we can take the prime factorization of $9797$. So $9797 = 97 \cdot 101$. What do we do next? Can someone write out a full example step by step?

Comment: how many totatives do these factors have?

Comment: 96 and 100 respectively.

Comment: okay so what is it mod these factors ?

Comment: So, $3^{100}\equiv a \pmod{97}$ and $3^{100}\equiv b\pmod{101}$.  Combining that information then via chinese remainder we have...

Comment: taking the mod it should be 1

Comment: @JohnLocke which mod?

Comment: 3^100≡b(mod101) , b= 1

Comment: so, two major steps left, you still need to find $a$ in $3^{100}\equiv a\pmod{97}$ and you still need to combine this new piece of information with the piece of information you just wrote in your last comment.

Comment: Can I do something like 3^93 * 3^4 ≡ 1 (mod 97)

Comment: I think you mean 3^96 * 3^4

Comment: @JohnLocke Without explicitly calculating, do you know $3^{93}\bmod 97$?

Comment: @peterwhy yes, $3^{93}$ mod 97 is 1

Comment: and then 3^4 = 81 so we get 3^100 ≡ 81 (mod 97)

Comment: @JohnLocke no 3^96 mod 97 is 1,   3^93 mod 97 is 18 ( I have PARI/GP a computer algebra system, and have done the computation with it). however your answer of 81 mod 97 is correct for 3^100 mod 97.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. I wanted to find 3^96 mod 97

Comment: that's given by fermat's little theorem ( a specific case of Euler's theorem) ...  next step is combining them with the Chinese Remainder Theorem ( aka CRT).

Comment: So now I have two expressions: 3^100 ≡ 1 (mod 101) and 3^100 ≡ 81 (mod 97). Can I just multiply my remainders and have my solution?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Computation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62826/discussion-between-john-locke-and-roddy-macphee).

Comment: Be aware that the accepted answer was incorrect. I posted a simpler correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $3^{96}\equiv1\pmod{97}$, hence  $3^{100}\equiv3^4=81$. Mod. $101$, $3^{100}\equiv 1$.

On the other hand, a *Bézout's relation* between $97$ and $101$ (obtained by the *extended  Euclidean algorithm*) is 
$$25\cdot97-24\cdot 101=1,$$
whence the solution of the system of congruences:
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv 81&\mod{97}\\ x\equiv 1&\mod{101}\end{cases}\iff
x\equiv1\cdot 25\cdot97-81\cdot24\cdot 101=-193919\equiv 2021 \pmod{9797}.$$

Comment: Why do you believe that $\ 25\mid 1?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque done modular arithmetic where that's possible, also you can look at it this way 25* 97- 101* 25 = -4 * 25 = -100 which is congruent ( not equal as you say) to 1 mod 101.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Thanks for pointing the typo! Fixed.

Comment: The answer is still incorrect (not only because of a typo).

Comment: See my answer for the correct value (simpler, and *all* work shown)

Comment: @BillDubuque: I wrongly reported the modulus for the final calculation. Is it correct now?

Comment: @Bernard, Yes, but you pulled the Bezout identity out of hat, which is cheating. You should show the work.

Comment: It's not cheating, in my opinion: everyone should know the method to obtain it (and I mention that method).

Comment: Well, when  I was teaching arithmetic, this was in the curriculum of last year high school students.

Answer (score 0):

${\rm mod}\ 101\:\,\ x\equiv 3^{100}\equiv\color{#c00}{\bf 1}\ $ by Fermat; and similarly

${\rm mod}\ 97\!:\,\ x\equiv 3^{100}\equiv 3^4\equiv 81\equiv\color{#c00} {\bf 1}\!+\!101k\equiv 1\!+\!4k\iff k\equiv 80/4\equiv 20$

Therefore $\,x \equiv 1+101(20)\equiv 2021\,\pmod{97\cdot 101}$